# Чи правильно використовувати фемінітиви в науковому стилі?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи правильно використовувати фемінітиви в науковому стилі? Наприклад, в науковій роботі? У ЗМІ вже активно застосовуються слова типу «лікарка», «мисткиня», «професорка» (https://tsn.ua/video/video-novini/u-kaliforniyi-mistkinya-obshila-unitaz-z-aksesuarami-vid-luyi-vittona.html), але жоден словник, здається, назв професій в жіночому роді не зафіксував. То як бути? Я знаю, що фемінітиви використовують. Але запитання про їх доцільність в наукових роботах! Питання це гостро стоїть перед написанням курсової роботи, адже різні науковці дотримуються різної думки.

Comment: Я знаю, що фемінітиви використовують. Але запитання про їх доцільність в наукових роботах! Питання це гостро стоїть перед написанням курсової роботи, адже різні науковці дотримуються різної думки.

Comment: Оскільки фемінітиви в українській мові переважають у розмовному стилі, публіцистичному та художньому, натомість не притаманні офіційно-діловому та науковому, то  їх використовувати НЕ рекомендавано, адже слід дотримуватися ЧИННОЇ норми (!) в науковому та офіційно-діловому стилях мови. Отже, у курсових роботах НЕ варто використовувати фемінітивів.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не зовсім так. Фемінітиви, зокрема і назви професій подаються у словниках.
Наприклад, сучасний [Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47800&page=1508):

> ЛІ́КАРКА, и, ж.
>    Жін. до лі́кар.
>
> Стара мати кидається .. до лікарки, то знов поспішається до знахарки (Марко Вовчок)
>
> МИСТКИ́НЯ, і, ж. Жін. до мисте́ць.
>
> Обдарувала музей відома мисткиня Катерина Росандіч-Кричевська, дочка Василя Кричевського (О. Шугай)

Щодо давніших, то [Словарь української мови в 4-х тт. за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) теж містить фемінітиви (хоч створений у 1907-1909 рр.):

> Професорка, ки, ж. Женщина-профессоръ. Желех. (т. 3, с. 487).

Слова такого ж типу є і в [Словнику української мови в 11 тт. за ред. І. Білодіда](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) (Т. 7, С. 333):

> ПРОФЕ́СОРКА, и, ж., розм.
>
> 1. Жінка-професор.
> 2. заст. Дружина професора. Пані професорка (чоловік її вже став справжнім професором) надумала урядити в себе журфікси для молоді… (Л. Укр., III, 1952, 592).

Щодо використання фемінітивів у різних стилях, зокрема і в науковому, то 
у [Вікіпедії] подана інформація, до речі з покликанням на *Довідник з культури мови: Посібник / За ред. С. Я. Єрмоленко. — К.: Вища школа, 2005. — С. 50-51.*, де вказано, що:

> Більшість порадників і підручників рекомендують дотримуватися чинної норми в науковому та офіційно-діловому стилях мови:
>
> **У науковому і офіційно-діловому стилях іменники жіночого роду на означення професій вживаються рідко**. У властивих їм мовних штампах спостерігаємо стійку традицію використання іменників чоловічого роду на позначення осіб жіночої статі.

Також ще натрапила на статтю [Фемінітиви: потреба мови чи курйозна забаганка?](http://instpres.univ.kiev.ua/node/1813), де повідомлено, що:

> "Фемінітиви в українській мові переважають у розмовному стилі, публіцистичному та художньому, натомість **не притаманні офіційно-діловому та науковому**."

Проте, сьогодні утворення від іменників чоловічого роду назв жіночого є продуктивним. Оскільки для нас абсолютно нормальним є вживання паралельних форм - *студент-студентка*, *філолог-філологиня*, *магістр-магістрантка* та ін., то, ймовірно, що через деякий час такого типу лексеми увійдуть і в науковий стиль.